# Access to many-to-many relation in array format, symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

in symfony we can access many-to-many relations with getter functions which return objects of ArrayCollection type.
for example for getting Alex's students we can call `$alex->getStudens()`, then i have access to ale's studens object.

now my question is how i can access alex's students id's in array, for example by calling `$alex->getStudentsIds()` it returns {1,5,7,12,..} , which are his students's ids.

Comment: Knowing your end-game would probably be more helpful than providing you with a `QueryBuilder` or a custom method that returns all this stuff. Doctrine is very powerful with Object Relational Mapping and you may be trying to use an `IN` functionality for a Query where `MEMBER OF` could be a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

precisely how you wrote it, you add another function in the entity

```
public function getStudentsIds()
{
   $students = $this->students;
   $studentIds = [];

   foreach($students as $student)
   {
     $studentIds[] = $student->getId();
   }  

   return $studentIds;
}
```

Ideal solution would be to add such a method to a repository and have it query only for student ids for given object but this is the simpliest solution possible.

Comment: It's also possible to use indexBy when setting up your relations.  In which case, a simple array_keys($students) will do the trick.

Comment: can you give an example of the query which you say that is more efficient? thanks :)

Comment: $repository->createQueryBuilder('q')->select('IDENTITY(q.students)')->where('q = :yourObject')->setParameter('yourObject',$yourObject)